# If I install the server version and then add all the GUI programs to it will I be able to get updates until 2015?

Tags: 10.04, alternate

I have an older laptop that maybe a bit too slow for 12.04, but it runs great on v10. 
I am about to re-install the 10.04 back on it, but I am trying to decide which version I should go with. I noticed that the Desktop version has a LTS support terms until April, 2013 (next year), but the server version is good till April, 2015.

So I am thinking if I install the server version and then add all the GUI programs to it - will I still be able to get updates till 2015?

Also, I can't seem to find any information about LTS End of life for the Alternate CD. Do you know what's the deal with that?

What would you recommend?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This confusion is probably why they made it so all [LTS releases are 5 years](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LTS/). :-) Since the desktop version of Ubuntu is simply a collection of packages, I would have to guess that that means those packages will not be supported after 4/2013. This would be all of the packages that make up the GUI, i.e. Gnome, etc. So, if you want to use a GUI with your laptop, I think you will be end of life after 4/2013, regardless of whether you install Ubuntu with the Server, Desktop or Alternate CD.

On a side note, have you tried [Xubuntu](http://xubuntu.org/)? It uses a different Window manager (Xfce), so it is much faster on older hardware. It uses the same core as Ubuntu, so you still have all the great advantages of using Ubuntu, and it follows the same release schedule.

Comment: Thanks, the kind of updates I am mostly interested in are for the server type software - FTP, PHP, MySQL, etc, even though I run it as a desktop as well. Do you know about their Alternate CD? I can't seem to find any mention of its EOL.

Comment: Like I said, it doesn't matter which CD you use to install Ubuntu that determines its EOL, it is the packages you install afterwards. Because of this, I would strongly suggest against installing  10.04 if you will have any sort of GUI interface on the laptop AND want to use it beyond April 2013. It is no fun when you reach EOL on Ubuntu, trust me from experience. :-) I would just try Xubuntu 12.04, as it will be fully supported for the next 5 years.

Comment: Ok, thanks again! I'll look into it. It appears that Xubuntu LTS is good for 3 years, not 5. Can you still use Ubuntu repositories to install/update XUbuntu software or would those programs have to be recompiled for XUbuntu? And what about just installing XFCE on Ubuntu?

Comment: Yes, they use all the same repos. Installing XFCE on Ubuntu is *basically* the same thing as installing Xubuntu, but if you just install Xubuntu, it won't install Gnome/Unity first, so you don't have to uninstall them. I want to say it also removes the system requirements from the installer, but I don't know for certain.

Comment: Okay, just to clarify, you need 256MB RAM and 2GB HDD to run the live installer for Xubuntu.